# Who stole my candy?

Tags: black-butler

This question may not have a current answer but I want to be sure that I am not missing critical detail.

In chapter 129 of Kuroshitsuji on page 13 there is an eerie message etched into a wall that reads,

> Who stole the candy from my tummy?

It is attached below with appropriate spoiler tags for anyone who hasn't read it yet.

Further in the chapter it is foreshadowed that Ciel has had some interaction with the persons who attacked the manor. However I do not recall who this is referencing or what arc.

Does anyone know? Or should I just wait for the future chapters?

> [image: Snip of eerie image]

Comment: For all who posted and drew traffic to this question. The newest chapter just released which is why I accepted an answer. If said answer is proven wrong then I will be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely "Ciel's" twin. In the latest chapter, after Agni dies, Soma punches "Ciel". This is not the only evidence, but this most likely proves the Double Ciel Theory is in fact true. I had this idea about how Sebastian addresses "Ciel". I think he had never called "Ciel" Ciel because if he called him that, he would be lying. Or, it could just be a sign of respect but.....Anyway, I really love this series and I wonder what will happen in the following chapters.
                                                   -Screwaloistrancy:)

Answer (score 2):

My theory, The candy is the phantomhive ring, which the real ciel swallowed to protect it when they were abducted. Somewhere in the chapter where sebastian was cut up by grell's death scythe and the cinematic record was shown, in the background one speech bubble says "should i be the one to take the ring out?" So, it means that the 'candy' he was referring to was the ring in which the current ciel took in his tummy

Answer (score 1):

The twin of ciel was stabbed in the "tummy" maybe the candy is the power of sebastian. In the previous chapter soma said to the agressor "do you feel sick again" wich mean that he look exactly the same as ciel. And in the "circus arc-atlantis arc" when they return in the past of ciel and sebastian when ciel say "i'm ciel phantomhive" sebastian answer by something like "i'm the only one who don't lie..." well all of this is just suposition ^^'

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm kind of getting a weird vibe that it perhaps could be the girl at the End of the Circus arc in which she see the manor burning down to the ground. It is true that at the end of the manga for that arc it show that the girl has Died and moved on to the next Life. However, we never see her truly Die if you know what I mean, perhaps seeing her old child self is a symbol in which that perhaps should could still be Alive however her old self was long gone and Dead and left to be with the gang.

I know I might be wrong in this but it's just a theory

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive it's Ciel's lost twin that has been revived. Maybe it's some inside joke from when they were younger? Sebastian has no idea what it means but Ciel's horror is evident. If his name even is Ciel....

I highly suggest people research the Twin-Ciel theory. It explains a lot in the manga.

Answer (score 1):

it could be lizzy as well, and candy in the tummy some kind of childhood joke between two. She was told to be proficient with swords and soma kinda was familiar with her, and he was the one who happily greeted the stranger who came. Both of them had short stature. and Lizzy's disappearance still must have some special reason

Answer (score 1):

To be completely honest, I think it could be Ciel's dad. Undertaker hinted at him being alive and it would make sense if it is him. He looks like Ciel, and could possibly be linked to the reason Lizzy doesn't want to go home.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the last theory of be Vincent, Undertaker's crying and telling the Earl is still with us. There is more, Agni and his murderer both were crouched while clashing, the Murderer is clearly taller than Ciel.

So, it's perfectly is plausible is be Vincent.